# react - function in component body

Tags: function, reactjs, higher-order-functions

I saw this code in a tweet and I don't understand how OnScreenResize is implemented such that width/height are supplied as arguments. I'm not assuming a familiarity with these components, particularly I'd just like to see how it might be implemented. i.e. how the children as a function is called and passed values

```
const LeftIcon = ({ onDrawerToggle }) => (
<OnScreenResize debounce={50} bounds={[400,500]}>
   {({ width, height }) => 
    width > smallTablet.value 
    ? Component(onDrawerToggle)
    : OtherComponent()}
</OnScreenResize>
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how `OnScreenResize` can be implemented:

```
class OnScreenResize extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      width: 0,
      height: 0    
    };
    this.updateWidthAndHeight = this.updateWidthAndHeight.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.updateWidthAndHeight();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWidthAndHeight);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateWidthAndHeight);
  }

  updateWidthAndHeight() {
    this.setState({
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { width, height } = this.state;
    return this.props.children({ width, height });
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome, I'll accept your solution. I've created a small test project and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `OnScreenResize` component, but it looks like it is expecting its `children` to be a function. That's not how most components work, but it is a valid component. So on render, `OnScreenResize` figures out the width and the height, and passes it to the function that is `this.props.children`. It then renders what is returned, which in this case will be one of two components depending on the screen width.

Edit: adding example implementation of `OnScreenResize` component.

```
const OnScreenResize = ({children}) => {
  let width = 100 // get width from browser
  let height = 100 // get height from browser
  // TODO: error check that children is actually a function instead of assuming.
  return children({width: width, height: height})
}
```

Comment: when React added stateless functional components (where you can define a component as just a render function) this syntax became possible.  It just defines an anonymous function value in place of a traditional React component.

Comment: I'm not expecting anyone to be familiar with that component, the question is hypothetical. I just want to see the code where width and height would get passed in